# How can I set a second screen (DISPLAY=:0.1) as the default gnome display?

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-panel, metacity

Due to various reasons, I have my main monitor set as the secondary display in `xorg.conf`. I would like to have gnome initialize `metacity`, `gnome-panel` as running primarily on `:0.1`, instead of `:0.0`. Is this possible at all?

To clarify, this is a laptop with its LCD turned off. My main monitor is connected to the VGA out and is driven by the `nouveau` driver for NVIDIA; a secondary monitor is on a displaylink usb-vga donverter. The seconday monitor is set in `xorg.conf` as the primary display (no way around it).

I can do things like `DISPLAY=:0.1 gnome-terminal` to run applications on the main monitor. My question is whether it is possible to do this (GNOME-) system-wide.

Comment: Disable the built-in lcd

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following thread is a partial solution (at least for the panels): http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1114767

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to put `export DISPLAY=:0.1` in `~/.gnomerc`, depending on `gnome-session` version and possibly distribution.